# How many choices do we have, When in our choices are not two members of a family.?

Tags: combinatorics

Assume that $m, n$ and $r$ are natural numbers such that $m=n+r^2$. Consider that we have $n+r$ families.   $n$ families have only one member and $r$ families  have $r$ members. Therefore, we have  $m$ persons. We want to choose $k$ people.How many choices do we have, When  in our choices are not two members of a family.

For example when $r=1$, we have $\left(\begin{array}{c}
 n+1  \\
  k 
\end{array}\right)$ choices.  Also, when $r=2$ and $k=2$,  we have  $\left(\begin{array}{c}
 n+4  \\
  2 
\end{array}\right)-2$  choices.

Comment: To get started, I'd note that you are choosing $a$ members from the single person families and $b$ families from the multi-member families where $a+b=k$.  Then, for each of the $b$, you choose one of the possible $r$, so you get a factor of $r^b$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From lulu's hint

$$\sum_{a=a_{min}}^{a_{max}}{n\choose a}\cdot{r\choose k-a}r^{k-a},$$

which $a_{max}$ and $a_{min}$ depends on $a \le\min(n,k)$ and $(k-a)\le r$, or combined as $\max(k-r,0)\le a\le\min(n,k)$. e.g. $r=2,\ k=2$ and $n=5$

$$\begin{alignat}{}
\sum_{a=0}^{2}{5\choose a}\cdot{2\choose 2-a}r^{2-a}\\
= 1\cdot1\cdot 2^2 + 5\cdot2\cdot2^1 + {5\choose2}\cdot1\cdot2^0\\
= 4+20+10=34,
\end{alignat}$$

which is the same as

$${5+4\choose2}-2.$$

But I'm wondering whether it is possible to represent the formula as $n,r,k$ only(without summation mark).